# Accessing the low 32-bits of r8 through r15

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

How can I write a 32-bit value to the low doubleword of the registers r8-r15 with asm()?
The following code won't compile:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {
    float f0,f1,f2=-2.4f;
    asm volatile
    (
        "movl %2, %%r8\n"
        "movl %%r8, %1\n"
        "movl %1, %%r15\n"
        "movl %%r15, %0"
        :"=r"(f0,f1)
        :"r"(f1,f2)
        :"%r8,%r15"
    );
    printf("%f\n",f0);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

The error I get:

```
unknown register name '%r8,%r15' in 'asm'
```

Note that It is a x64 program so r8-r15 registers should be available.

Comment: The syntax you use is wrong, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers

Comment: The actual syntax error is caused by putting two register names into one string, and a `,` operator in an output constraint.  (The `,` operator does not produce an lvalue).  Fixing the input / output constraints, and using `"r8", "r15"` would have compiled (but then not assemble, because you're using `movl` (32-bit operand size) with 64-bit registers.)  Note that with gcc, filling in the asm template string is separate from assembling the resulting text into machine code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use r8d to access the low 32 bits of r8. Note that when you write to r8d (or any 32-bit register in 64-bit mode), it clears the upper 32 bits. There is no way to write to the low 32 bits and preserve the upper 32 bits.

Comment: "Note that when you write to r8d, it clears the upper 32 bits." BTW that's true for all 64 bit registers, not just r8-r15.